# Compare images in S3 bucket by using AWS face recognition

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Actually my requirement is to upload images to S3 bucket(it can be million) and then compare face of uploaded image on my server with these millons bucket's images by using AWS Face recognition api in php.

Please help me and save me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/use-amazon-rekognition-to-build-an-end-to-end-serverless-photo-recognition-system/) and [Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-your-own-face-recognition-service-using-amazon-rekognition/) are couple of blogs detailing the process of how we can use AWS Rekognition service to build it end to end.

Key point to note is:

We can't run faceDetection against entire S3 repository it will be extremely expensive and timetaking, we need to use Amazon Face Collection, to store the facial features of each photo we add to S3 and run matchFaces Api against the collection, not the S3 repository.

we mainly need to use three APIs:

1. [Face Detection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/faces.html): To detect faces in an image and crop the faces.
2. [indexFaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_IndexFaces.html): To index the cropped faces to a collection.
3. [Search Faces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/collections.html): To facial match a photo against our collection.

Comment: Agreed. Just to clarify: Each photo first needs to be loaded into a Face Collection using [`IndexFaces()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-rekognition-2016-06-27.html#indexfaces). Then, when you want to compare an uploaded photo to all of those pre-indexed faces, use [`SearchFacesByImage()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-rekognition-2016-06-27.html#searchfacesbyimage).